# Impedance matching 133 MHz - Topology and terminating resistor concerns

Tags: spi, impedance, impedance-matching, signal-integrity, termination

I am using the QSPI bus of the RP2040 to talk to a flash chip.  I am also putting 8 more chips (PSRAMs) on that bus in my design, and a second RP2040 to load them. The datasheet for the RP2040 isn't explicit, but some measurements and calculations suggest the QSPI bus driving impedance is ~40 Ω. The PSRAM chips I'm using all have 50 Ω driver impedance.

I've built a prototype, but my reads are erroring inconsistently at the speeds I'm using (133 MHz QSPI clock from a 2x overclocked RP2040 with a divider of 2). Certain chips error more than others, and I think reflected signals are playing a role. I've never done impedance matching before, but I've spent a long while reading up on and I feel comfortable with the theory.

My layout right now is suboptimal, and I think I'm going to have to change it - but I would still appreciate solutions on how to terminate without changing the layout.  It's safe to consider my current layout as basically a star, but each leg of the star has a slightly different length. Very technically, the actual layout is more of an "H": the bottom two branches each hold an RP2040, and then the other two branches each hold 4 of the PSRAMs. The flash is on the same branch as one of the RP2040s.

A picture is worth 1000 words and all - note that the traces are not currently impedance matched, but I plan on doing that.

[image]

If I only had one transmitter, I would just put a parallel termination resistor at the opposite end. However, each of the PSRAMs AND both the RP2040s might be transmitters (for at least data, obviously the clock is only coming from one of the RP2040s), the situation is more complicated.

My big question:

- How do you terminate this kind of multi-transmitter, branched transmission network?

If I'm honest, I don't know if there's a clean or good way to do so - I've seen some posts suggesting resistors to establish impedance-matched branches, but with my weird topology I don't know if that's doable.

My plan right now: Re-run the traces so the bus is essentially a snake that starts at one RP2040, runs from there through all the PSRAMs and the flash, and ends at the other RP2040 without any branches.  If I do that, I think I have an understanding of how to terminate things.

Here, have an ugly picture:

[image]

If I make the transmission lines 100 Ω, and then put a 100 Ω terminating resistor in parallel with each line right at the bus end on the RP2040 - where the bus ends - then I think every transmitter on the bus will see the same thing:  The RP2040s will each see (A) a 100 Ω resistor "transmission line" directly to ground, and (B) a 100 Ω real transmission line along the bus. Taken in parallel, these give a 50 Ω impedance which matches (roughly) the RP2040's driver impedance - thus no reflections.

Each PSRAM or flash along the long bus will see 2 transmission lines in parallel: (A) one going toward RP2040 #1, and (B) one going toward RP2040 #2, at the other end of the bus. Each line is 100 Ω impedance, so in parallel it should be 50 Ω, which matches the driver on the PSRAMs.

The big questions here:

- Is this approach good?  Is there a better approach?
- Is two 100 Ω transmission lines in parallel a good match for a 50 Ω impedance driver?
- Is terminating with 100 Ω resistors at either end of the bus appropriate/correct?
- If I do this, I will have to use some vias to connect up the bus. How bad are vias for signal integrity at 133 MHz?

Comment: Is the problem really about termination, or simply chips failing to work as specified, becaust they are overclocked to 2x the specified speed? It's a miracle they work at all, no manufacturer guarantees operation beyond rated limits.

Comment: The RP2040 at OC 2x is just fine (I've seen OC to 400+ Mhz, and briefly to 1GHz), the and the PSRAMs are rated for 133MHz QSPI.  If it so happens that the RP2040 is the problem, I will deal with that separately: I'd still like to know how best to terminate and impedance match the bus.  This is definitely a question about termination.

Comment: Manufacturer documentation says maximum system clock is 133 MHz, no mention of overclocking supported. Even if someone else got one chip running at 1 GHz or 400+ MHz, it does not mean your chip will work perfectly with zero problems at 2x the maximum rate. First rule out if it's the overclocking that ruins your day, then figure out what kind of termination issues you have when everything runs at normal clocks. You might not need any termination. What impedance are your PCB tracea designed for?

Comment: For the sake of learning, let's assume that the overclock is not the problem.  I know in practice that might not be true - but the way I see it, there are a two options:

1) The overclock is not causing problems, but ringing/reflections on the bus are causing problems.  If this is the case, I need to figure out how to optimize my bus design on the PCB to avoid problems.

2) The overclock is causing problems.  To give the RP2040 the best chance at working, I need to optimize the bus design on the PCB (but it still might fail).

Comment: Either way, I want to learn about bus termination/signal impedance matching, _regardless_ of whether that will fix all my issues for this specific application: I may run into star-topology termination issues in future projects that have nothing to do with my specific choice of chip in this problem.

Comment: In answer to your question: my PCB traces are not currently targeting ANY specific impedance, I didn't think I would have to worry about it.  Now I'm trying to optimize everything before ordering a new revision to save cost.